# livepatch problem ERROR has anyone else ran into this?

Tags: 18.04, canonical-livepatch

[image]

anyone else ran in this problem in 18.04.2 LTS?

Comment: On my system, the `snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd` service always fails at startup, so I disabled it.

Comment: You are not alone in experiencing this. Within the last couple of days my 18.04.2 does the same with the latest kernel and its predecessor. None of the suggested fixes works for me, so I will wait for an Ubuntu update to correct it.